# Trying to return the names of people within a winForm listbox

Tags: c#

I'm essentially adding to a list; iterating those names through a listbox using a for..loop.

However, it's not showing any names once I've entered a name/age; click add person and show people; nothing displays whatsoever.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GUI_TEST_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Person_List> people = new List<Person_List>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void addPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = addName.Text;

            int age = Convert.ToInt32(addAge.Text);

            for (int i = 0; i < people.Count(); i++)
            {
                people[i].addPersonToList(name, age);
            }
        }

        private void showPeople_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < people.Count(); i++)
            {
                string name = people[i].showPeople();

                peopleListBox.Items.Add("Name: " +  name);
            }
        }

        private void peopleListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GUI_TEST_2
{
    class Person_List
    {
        public List<Person> listOfPeople = new List<Person>();

        public Person_List()
        {
        }

        public void addPersonToList(string name, int age)
        {
            listOfPeople.Add(new Person(name, age));
        }

        public string showPeople()
        {
            string name = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfPeople.Count(); i++)
            {
                name = listOfPeople[i].Name;
            }

            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not appear to have any `Person_List` objects added to the `people` object.

Comment: For what i see `people` is empty and you never add any element (at least in the code you posted).

Comment: You have a list of lists.  The initial list of lists is empty, which is why nothing is being added in addPerson_Click

Comment: I think I understand; due to the fact that I never add an object to the listOfPeople inside Person_List; it has no index to iterate through anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the addPerson_Click event you loop over your list people but this list does not contain anything then you never call addPersonToList.

Try with somehting like :

```
Person_List people = new Person_List();

private void addPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = addName.Text;

    int age = Convert.ToInt32(addAge.Text);

    people.addPersonToList(name, age);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You gotta add the ppl to the listbox after adding them to the listOfPeople-list. Addin them to the listOfPeople doesn't mean that they automaticly get added to the listbox. There is no two-way binding as far as I know.

How I would implement

```
showPeople(){
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var ppl in listOfPeople)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(ppl)
    }
}
```